# Which performs a faster fetch, using SELF IN or ==?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

Say I have an entity called `User` and an entity called `Message`. A user has several messages (to-many relationship) and a message only has one author.

Say now that I wanted to get all messages by this user. I have two options:

1. `predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@ ", user.messages];`
2. `predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"authorEmail == %@ ", user.email];`

Which would be faster and why? Assume that the user's `email` is indexed.

Comment: Oh and the reason I would even want to fetch a user's messages via SELF IN user.messages even though I already have them in the relationship is so that I can put them in an NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: The performance tool can help you figure this out. Set up a test program that does a ton of these operations, and run it through the profiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you care about performance, don't re-fetch. Fetching is **always** expensive because fetching **always** has to read from the file system (by convention). If you already have the data in memory, simply use a UITableViewController without a NSFetchedResultsController.

If you don't care about performance, then it doesn't matter either way.

Comment: That is not accurate. Fetching is inexpensive unless it fires a fault. Even then it does not automatically mean that persistent store needs to be read from if the data is available in row cache. Only if it is a fault AND unavailable in cache will it be read from disk.

Comment: That is NOT true. Executing an NSFetchRequest will **always** touch the file system and fetch objects from the database. **Always**. No matter if there's a fault or not. No matter if the object is in memory already or not.

Comment: What you say is simply not true Daniel. Core Data maintains a row cache which will be checked first before a trip to the persistent store is made. Also, you can easily test this. If you have an object (not faulted) brought into context, and you make modifications to the same object in the persistent store through another context, your original context will be unaware of the changes when you fetch. Only when you use -refreshObject:mergeChanges: will it be updated from the persistent store or parent context. You can easily verify my claim on the cache by using Instruments and Core Data stack.

Comment: It *is* true when we're talking about NSFetchRequest. By contract NSFetchRequest will always go to the file system. This is very different from how faulting works. You can simply test this: Set `com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug` to `1` and execute the same fetch request over and over again. You'll see that it will touch the database each and every single time. NSFetchRequest will fetch from the database regardless of the row cache.

Comment: I agree that the SQL statements will be executed. I'm just saying it will not hit the actual filesystem IO, but will be served from in-memory cache instead.

Comment: What makes you think it will be served from in-memory cache? The row cache sits above the SQL layer. If you're executing SQL, you'll touch the file system. SQL has to by contract. It is not allowed to return cached values, since the representation in the file system may have changed below it.

Comment: The fact that there is such thing as cache hits and misses in instruments for fetches hints in favor of cache being used in between persistent store file and managed object context. NSFetchRequest class reference says there is a row cache and it is used "if available" before going to read the data from disk. But it is not 100% clear in itself whether this includes only firing faults or explicit fetches. And what can be easily observed by testing is that core data does not in fact refetch the values from persistent store for an object that has been brought to the context previously.